# Convert binary to decimal using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I was trying to come up with a solution in C++ to convert binary to decimal. It works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power = 1;
int sum = 0;

int deci (int k) {
    if (k == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        sum += power * (k % 10) + deci(k / 10);
        power *= 2;
        return sum;
    }
        
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << deci(n);
}
```

Pretty standard stuff, works my way backward from the last digit to the first digit, multiplying each digit with its corresponding power of 2.

But then for some reason when I removed the line updating the powers of 2 that will be used to calculate corresponding power values it still works??? For example input is 1101 it outputs 13, input 101 output 5, all accurate with the numbers I've tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power = 1;
int sum = 0;

int deci (int k) {
    if (k == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        sum += power * (k % 10) + deci(k / 10);
        //power *= 2;
        return sum;
    }
        
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << deci(n);
}
```

I've racked my brain out trying to rationalise why the second code even works but failed to. I'd appreciate any insight. Thank you.

Comment: ***I've racked my brain out trying to rationalise why the second code even works but failed to*** Don't you have access to a computer with a debugger so you can step though the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables and flow after each individual line is executed? This is what I do pretty much every time I can't understand the behavior of code.

Comment: *I was trying to come up with a solution in C++ to convert binary to decimal* -- `sum += power * (k % 10) + deci(k / 10);` -- Even without using a debugger, you could have put in `cout` statements to see what each part of the formula is that you're using.  There is no shame in breaking up a long line of code into several pieces, and then inspect each piece.

Comment: Regardless, recursion with static variable state - yuk.  Nasty and unnecessary - as if recursion alone was not bad enough.